# search_api facet_api: multiple query, single index, single page

Tags: search, views

I have single index in search_api, on my page I render several views over this search index. On the breakpoint when I want to render my facets in `search_api_current_search()` I got an array of searches.

I know what element to render, but how can I render facets from this particular search query?

I render the facets using

```
$adapter = facetapi_adapter_load('search_api@' . $index);
$p = $adapter->buildRealm('somerealm');
$children = element_children($p);
```

where $index is the search index, but all the queries on the page using this index, and assumes that it uses the last search query.